# Is it possible to integrate Patreon OAuth this way in my MERN stack project?

Tags: express, authentication, oauth, mern

Folder structure:

```
/client     
  /dist         
    index.html <-- production build     
  /src      
    App.js 
/server     
   server.js
```

I'm implementing Patreon OAuth for a project. All I want to do for right now is have patrons be able to connect and have
the ability to display their name and image once redirected back after approving the authorization request.

Right now, I'm doing the token authorization and the user data fetching in a server side route when the redirect happens. I need to be able to redirect back to the root route, thats where the client code is located in production. How can I consume the data in the React code in this case?

```
app.get("/oauth/redirect", async (req, res, next) => {
    //getting code appended in redirected url
    //using code to get access_token and refresh_token
    //call patreon api using token in authorization header to get user data back
    //not sure what to do with the data...? 
})
```